# ¿Como guardar el estado de la página web?

Tags: php, html

soy un estudiante y me mandaron a hacer una página web que encienda y apague un ventilador, lo que coloque fue una imagen que actúa como tal. Mi problema es que no se guarda el estado del ventilador(encendido o apagado) y me gustaría saber como hacer que se guarde el ultimo estado para que al abrir nuevamente la página aparezca como se dejo la ultima vez. !Gracias de antemano¡

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div align="center"><img id="myImage" src="pic_fanoff.gif" style="width:400px"></div>
  <div align="middle"> 
    <input type=submit value="Prender" 
      onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_fanon.gif'">
    <input type=submit value="Apagar" 
      onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_fanoff.gif'">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Investiga sobre cookies y localstorage.

Comment: podrias hacerlo con php

Answer (score 0):

pues asi por el navegador talves te sirva **localStorage**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>

    function prender()
    {
        localStorage.setItem("estado", document.getElementById("estado").value);

        mostrarDatos();
    }


    function mostrarDatos()
    {
        var resultado="Estado: "+localStorage.getItem("estado");

        document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML=resultado;
    }

    window.onload=function()
    {

        mostrarDatos();

        if(localStorage.getItem("estado")!=null)
            document.getElementById("resultado").value=localStorage.getItem("estado");

    }
    </script>

    <style>
    input[type=button] {width:280px;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>



<form onSubmit="return false;">

    <select id="estado" name="estado">
        <option value="Prendido">Prendido</option>
        <option value="Apagado">Apagado</option>
    </select>

    <br><input type="button" value="guardar estado" onclick="prender()">

    <br>

    <div id="resultado"></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

o si es con PHP necesitaras una Base de Datos

Answer (score 0):

este es un pequeño ejemplo de lo que estas buscando adaptalo con imagenes

```html
<html>
     <head>
      <script>
      function cambiar() {
       boton.innerHTML=boton.innerHTML=="apagado"?"prendido":"apagado";
      }
      </script>
     </head>
     <body>
      <p><h1 id="boton">apagado</h1></p>
      <button id="cambiar" onclick="cambiar()">BOTON</button>
     </body>
    </html>
```